# Sine function from 0 to 2*pi with Step 0.1

Tags: excel, vba

I got a question on a programming course.

Question: Create a table that will show the following:

Function Sine from 0 to 2*pi with Step 0.1.

I made it this way :

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
Dim s As Double
Dim ret As String
Const pi = 3.14159265
For s = 0 To 2 Step 0.1
    ret = ret + Chr(10) + Str(Sin(s) * pi)
Next s
MsgBox ret
End Sub
```

I feel it is not right. I don't know where to place the Pi so it creates what they want. I'm only allowed to use Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SIN()` function expects radians already, no conversion is needed. I suggest:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim s As Double
    Dim ret As String
    Const pi = 3.14159265

    For s = 0 To 2 * pi Step 0.1
        ret = ret & Chr(10) & Str(Sin(s))
    Next s

    MsgBox ret
End Sub
```

I also suggest placing the results in cells rather than using the `MsgBox` since there are a lot of them.
I also suggest using the ***&*** rather than the ***+*** to build the `ret` string.
I also suggest using indentation and whitespace to make the code easier to follow.